# How to create email signature in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I'm using Gmail and have been invited to try Google Inbox but the problem is how can I add my own signature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was shut down in April, 2019, and is no longer available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a signature in Google Inbox by following [this tutorial](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/em4BKu2MRGw;context-place=forum/inbox). It says

**How to create a signature in Inbox**

1. Open Inbox.
2. In the top left, go to the main menu.
3. Scroll down and choose Settings.
4. On mobile, choose your account.
5. Select Signature settings.
6. Make sure the setting is switched to On.
7. Enter your signature in the text box.

* To see this update on mobile, make sure you're using the updated version of the Inbox app.

**Bonus point!**

You can just copy paste your signature in Gmail by following this

1. Open Gmail.
2. Click the gear in the top right.
3. Select Settings.
4. Scroll down to the “Signature” section and just copy your old signature text in the box.
5. Go back to Google Inbox signature then simply paste it.

Comment: Thank you so much for migrating and spending effort in editing my answer and question! Yeah, this topic should be in webapps, not in superuser.